# UILocalnotification with NTP/Timeserver

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uilocalnotification

My app needs to fire a couple of UILocalnotifications, however these depend on the system time and I can't get them to use NTP from example, https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp

The script works but doesn't fix the UILocalnotifications times.

E.G. This is my notification script (update's from Martin R.)

```
NSTimeInterval timeAdjustment = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate networkDate]];

NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setHour:15];
[comps setMinute:58];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

alarm.fireDate = [fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeAdjustment];
alarm.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
alarm.soundName = @"default";
alarm.alertBody = @"NTP Test..";
alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

The notification should go off at 15.58, the real time is 15.00 but the user wants to display the notification on 15.01 so he "hacks" the device time to 15.57 so the device will display the notification in a minute.
How can I prevent this, since it necessary for my app to work.
I tried adding NTP to my project, it loads but it doesn't work:

```
#import "AsyncUdpSocket.h"
#import "lib/ios-ntp.h"

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    [NSDate networkDate];
}
```

Comment: AFAIK notifications are set according to system time. The changes you make to NSDate will only be isolated within your application

Comment: @SuhailPatel Didn't know that, is there a way I can apply it to my notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compute the difference between device date and network date:

```
NSTimeInterval *timeAdjustment = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate networkDate]]
```

and adjust the notification's fire date accordingly:

```
fireDate = [fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeAdjustment];
```

Comment: I tried this now, however it didn't come up with a notification on the right time. Please see my updated code with your suggestion above. Thanks.

Comment: @user2460028: When does the notification fire? Perhaps also show the NSLog output of `timeAdjustment`, `fireDate` (before and after the adjustment) and of `alarm`.

Comment: No, the notification doesn't run at all, I tried NSLogging `timeAdjustment , fireDate` but the App won't run then it gives me this error: `Passing 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double') to parameter of incompatible type 'NSString *'`

Comment: @user2460028: `NSLog(@"timeAdjustment=%f", timeAdjustment)`, `NSLog(@"fireDate=%@", fireDate)` and `NSLog(@"alarm=%@", alarm)` should work.

Comment: @user2460028: Does the notification work if you don't adjust the time?

Comment: Okay, so NSlog is now showing the times. Only the times are wrong from the timeserver, at least that's how it looks like. The time server is located in the orgin country and returns the right time for other non-IOS apps. `timeAdjustment=-0.008302`
`fireDate=0001-01-01 13:41:28 +0000` it displays this time if the alert is set for 14.01 and the device time is 14.00

Comment: @user2460028: You have only set hour/minute in the date components, which means that year/month/day are undefined, hence the fire date in year 0001. You have to set year/month/day as well.

Comment: This code works fine even without the year/month/day since I've set `alarm.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;` the notification goes off now, but still at the time of the device and not the NTP time.

Comment: Note that `NSLog(@"alarm=%@", alarm)` also prints "next fire date = ...", so you can check that as well.

Comment: Alright, the NSLog firedate reports a different time than the NSLog alarm: `fireDate=2013-06-17 13:46:00 +0000` - `next fire date = maandag 17 juni 2013 15:45:59 Midden-Europese zomertijd` (Translates to monday 17 june 2013 15:45:59 Central European Summertime) the firedate's time is right the time the alarm nslog show is not. Unfortunately the alarm nslog time is being used.

Comment: NSLog prints a date always in UTC time, so `fireDate=2013-06-17 13:46:00 +0000` is the same as `15:46:00 CEST` and that is quite close to the `next fire date = 15:45:59 CEST`. When do you expect it to fire? - (It seems that we are in the same time zone Netherlands/Germany :-)

Comment: Allright, I didn't know that (and yes we are in the same timezone). However, on a normal device the alarm doesn't ring with the fixed code, in the simulator the device ignores the NTP time and just rings it on the device time. I'm unsure why this is, maybe it's not possible with an UILocalNotification?

Comment: @user2460028: It gets a bit confusing to me know. Perhaps one can separate the problem into two independent questions: 1) is the "next fire date" computed as you expect it (device/simulator)? - 2) does the notification fire at the time that was shown as "next fire date" (device/simulator)?

Comment: Nevermind, I think the device bug is an iOS 7 issue! I will test this a couple of times in the simulator now and will accept this answer when It works, thank you very much!

Comment: You are my hero, thanks a ton! It works now. I guess iOS 7 is a bit to beta for the moment. Thanks once again for your time!

Comment: @user2460028: You are welcome! (If you think that you found a bug in iOS 7 beta then you should file a bug at bugreporter.apple.com)